# How to disable folding while typing?

Tags: insert-mode, folding

I'm programming mostly in Python/Cython and use `foldmethod=syntax` (and `foldclose=`). Overall, this works fairly well, i.e. functions/classes/methods are folded reliably  mostly. However, I have one problem: folds are often opend/closed while I'm typing. Specifically,

- While working on an indented block (usually a long multiline argument list or a long list/dict/... initialization spanning multiple lines), that very **block I'm in is folded** when I hit return;
- When starting a string at the end of a block, the **block below is unfolded**.

This is all very annoying and distracting.

**Is there a way to completely disable any auto-folding while I type?**

Functionalities I want to retain:

- **Fold/unfold blocks I'm in** with a command/keystroke (I'm usually using `z-a` for both).
- **Fold the whole document** with a single keystroke/command.
- **Open new buffers fully folded** (though it's not a deal-breaker if I have to do this manually).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to completely disable folding (i.e. open all folds) while typing, see [D. Ben Knoble's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22443/26400).

If you'd just like to prevent Vim from opening and closing folds based on syntax while typing, leaving closed folds closed, check out Vim tip ["Keep folds closed while inserting text"](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text) or the [FastFold plugin](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold).  These use a variation on that theme with `foldmethod=manual` instead of `nofoldenable` during Insert mode:

```
augroup folds
  au!
  au InsertEnter * let w:oldfdm = &l:foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual
  au InsertLeave *
        \ if exists('w:oldfdm') |
        \   let &l:foldmethod = w:oldfdm |
        \   unlet w:oldfdm |
        \ endif |
        \ normal! zv
augroup END
```

The `normal! zv` at the end serves to ensure that, if you typed something that would result in a new fold, your cursor doesn't get folded into it when you leave Insert mode.  You could also experiment with `zx`, or just remove it if that doesn't matter to you.

Comment: While this works great for "standard" Vim usage, those of us who prefer evim (i.e., a *real* graphical editor) won't find much help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just disable folding in insert mode, and restore it when you leave:

```
augroup folds
  au!
  au InsertEnter * let w:oldfen = &l:foldenable \| set nofoldenable
  au InsertLeave *
        \ if exists('w:oldfen')
        \   let &l:foldenable = w:oldfen
        \   unlet w:oldfen
        \ endif
augroup END
```

Comment: This opens all the folds when you enter Insert mode, which seems like the sort of visual distraction that the question is trying to avoid.  How about setting `foldmethod=manual` during Insert mode instead of `nofoldenable`?  You could also add something like `normal zv` on InsertLeave to make sure your cursor doesn't get immediately folded into a new block.

Comment: I read « disable folding » as, well, disabling it

Comment: Fair enough.  I've made a separate answer in case anyone is looking for a solution to the alternate reading. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is an Indented language, The easier solution is to set `foldmethod=indent`. The crux of this solution is when you initialize list(or any code) in multiple lines, then they also get folded in a separate fold which is unwanted.

But vim does have syntax fold support for python out of the box, As suggested below in comment, running `:help ft-python-indent` gives:

> Indent after an open paren:
>
> > ```
> >    let g:pyindent_open_paren = '&sw * 2'
> > ```
>
> Indent after a nested paren:
>
> > ```
> >   let g:pyindent_nested_paren = '&sw'
> > ```
>
> Indent for a continuation line:
>
> > ```
> >    let g:pyindent_continue = '&sw * 2'
> > ```

For more details, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789615/6299181) or run `:help fold-commands`

Comment: vim does have out-of-the-box support for python..  see `:help ft-python-indent`